# Entity Framework Code First - Ignore complete entity

Tags: ef-code-first, entity

Is there an easy solution for the following situation:
I've got an Entity `Dossier` which is shared in 2 `DbContexts`.
`Dossier` has 2 navigation properties, `DossierType` and `DossierAttachment`

> Dossier
>
> Dossier --> DossierType (Navigation Property)
>
> Dossier --> DossierAttachment (Navigation Property)

I want to exclude the `DossierType` Entity in `DbContext1`. I do not want it to be savable to database, navigation properties should not be set.

I was expecting that calling

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<DossierType>();
```

in the `DbContext1.OnModelCreating` would be sufficient. It should make sure that my navigation property `DossierType` was not 'taken into context'.
It however gives following exception:

> The navigation property 'DossierType' is not a declared property on type 'Dossier'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

This exception will keep coming unless I call the Ignore on the navigation property explicitly, which I do not want. (My *reallife* scenario has a lot more navigation properties, I do not want to iterate these)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dossier>().Ignore(x => x.DossierType);
```

Is there any easy way to ignore specific entity types in an easy straight forward manner? Or should I really go for a reflection way: declaring a list of types which I don't want and ignore them using reflection?

Comment: I would love an answer to this one.